# Add text while exporting charts using chart.js

Tags: javascript, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js, export-to-image

These is my code to export a chart as an image, but i am not able to add text to it. Please help out to solve this issue.add only the exporting part, if u need full code i'll forward you.

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="500"></canvas>
    <br/><br/>
    <button id="save-btn">Save Chart Image</button>
  </div>

  <script>
    $("#save-btn").click(function() {
      $("#canvas").get(0).toBlob(function(blob) {
        saveAs(blob, "chart_1.png");
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: where do you want  to add text?

Comment: Do you want to add text as part of the chart? Do you want to add free positioned text on the image? Please be more specific.